# Repository fetch failure

Tags: 12.10, apt, updates, proxy

These are the errors I get:

(as you can see, I connect to the internet from the education department proxy)

```
W:Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'educf.proxy.tas.edu.au:8080' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'educf.proxy.tas.edu.au:8080' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

[CUT OUT SOME RESULTS, TOO MANY LINKS]

E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: if there are too many links, use paste.ubuntu.com. also, please run `ping 8.8.8.8` in a terminal and post the results.

Comment: This is most probably a DNS issue. `apt-get` could not resolve your proxy's address. There are two ways to fix this: change your proxy settings to point to an IP instead of `educf.proxy.tas.edu.au`, or check your DNS settings. Can you browse the internet normally? What is the output of the command `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: The root issue is DNS. Check for useful response (or error codes) when you run: **`dig au.archive.ubuntu.com`** or **`dig extras.ubuntu.com`**